# How to partially edit the section headers in the table of contents and the document for selected sections only?

Tags: bibliographies, sectioning, texmaker, sectsty

I have a table of contents with several sections, sub-sections, and sub-sub-sections. I want to keep these formatted in the same way throughout the table of contents and the document with the exception of the `Appendix` Section.

As an example, consider the two screenshots below:

[image: example 1 -- Appendix A]

Note the `(1)` in front of `Appendix A`. I would like to remove this from both the header in the top screenshot and the table of contents entry in the bottom screenshot. However, I would like to leave these entries unchanged for all sections that are not `Section VI. Appendices`.

[image: example 2 -- Table of Contents]

**How can I achieve this?** I have tried using the `\subsection*{Appendix A - ...}` but this removes the entry from the table of contents.

Just in case it is helpful, the preamble I am using (containing all additional packages) is below:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[labelfont=bf,textfont=md]{caption}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[margin=1.0in]{geometry}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage{sectsty}

\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}

\sectionfont{\LARGE}
\subsectionfont{\Large}
\subsubsectionfont{\large}
\paragraphfont{\large}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\ceil{\lceil}{\rceil}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\floor{\lfloor}{\rfloor}

\newenvironment{conditions}
  {\par\vspace{\abovedisplayskip}\noindent\begin{tabular}{>{$}l<{$} @{${}={}$} l}}
  {\end{tabular}\par\vspace{\belowdisplayskip}}

\pagenumbering{roman}
\renewcommand\cftchapaftersnum{.}
\renewcommand\cftsecaftersnum{.}

\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}

\renewcommand\thechapter{\alph{chapter}}
\renewcommand\thesection{\Roman{section}}
\renewcommand\thesubsection{(\arabic{subsection})}
\renewcommand\thesubsubsection{(\alph{subsubsection})}

\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
\begin{document}
```

I am relatively new to this stackexchange and LaTeX. If I can improve this question, please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Took days of searching, but the solution is short and easy to implement.

```
\newpage 

\section{Appendix}

\subsection*{Appendix A - Methods to Optimize Speed Distribution Fit}
\addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{Appendix A - Methods to Optimize Speed Distribution Fit}

<Put body here>
```